# GridView data is filled up by using LINQ To DataSet

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm new in LINQ & filling GridView through LINQ. Please see my code :

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mas"]);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string Query = string.Empty;

 private void Bind_LINQ_To_DataSet()
    {
        Query = "select * from dbo.Movie";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, connection);
        da.Fill(ds, "dbo.Movie");
        var tbl = from p in ds.Tables["dbo.Movie"].AsEnumerable()
                  where p.Field<int>("ID") == Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
                  select p;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
            GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bind_LINQ_To_DataSet();
    }
```

My GridVIew comes empty. Any suggestion really appreciate.

Comment: I hope gridview has all the column names specified in the UI?

Comment: No, I have not specified. I'm using Autogenerated column binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this :

```
       IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
                          from c in ds.Tables["dbo.Movie"].AsEnumerable()
                          where c.Field<int>("ID") == Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
                          select c;
        DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = boundTable ;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use **new** in **select** to specify columns.

Try this:

```
var datasource = from r in ds.Tables["dbo.Movie"].AsEnumerable()
        where r.Field<int>("ID") == Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
        select 
        new { FirstName = r.Field<String>("firstname"), LastName = r.Field<string>("lastname") };
```

or use this:

```
GridView1.DataSource =  tbl.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Samiey but if my table has 30 column then writing every column name is very length. Can I bind all the data directly to Grid.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the ***[AsDataView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908061.aspx)*** method:

```
GridView1.Visible = true;
GridView1.DataSource = tbl.AsDataView();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

No need to take into account the  number of columns.

OR you can also use `CopyToDataTable()` method

```
GridView1.Visible = true;
GridView1.DataSource = tbl.CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```